# Initializing useNavigate gives blank screen

Tags: reactjs

Not sure why, but every time I initialize useNavigate, I get a blank screen.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const About = () => {
    let navigate = useNavigate(); 
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => {
                navigate("/");
            }}>
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default About;
```

This is just a test I was trying out to see if I was messing up with my other project, but I'm getting the same result.
I'm sure there' something incredibly simple I'm missing, but I don't know what. I'm still new to react and any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not react-router but you're trying to access a route which does not exist, if you've renamed your home route in App.js like that:`<Route path='/Home' element={<Home />} />`
,replace it like that: `<Route path='/Home' element={<Home />} />`to match exact path

Comment: Thank you very much. That seemed to clear it up. I greatly appreciate your help! :)